# How can I use SQL Profiler to capture a single stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, profiler

Using SQL Server SQL Profiler, which configuration can be used to monitor a single stored procedure? I'd like to capture all `EXEC sprocName` to include the parameter list. I'd like to capture this procedure so that I can load test it using realistic parameter data.

I've tried the following in a new SQL Profiler trace:

```
Events Selection > Column Filters > Text Data > LIKE: 'exec sprocName%'
Events Selection > Column Filters > Text Data > LIKE: 'exec sprocName'
```

Neither of above configurations capture my procedure. I've also tried to remove the procedure name with the following configs:

```
Events Selection > Column Filters > Text Data > LIKE: 'exec%'
Events Selection > Column Filters > Text Data > LIKE: 'exec'
```

Above configs do not capture any procedures.

Finally, I tried to execute the same profile *without* any column filters and I can confirm that it captures all SQL queries sent to SQL Server.

I've considered a workaround of capturing ALL stored procedure execs and post-filtering to my sproc of interest, using SQL queries or Excel Power Query.  However, the high frequency of sproc executions in the environment I want to model, make this unfeasible.

Comment: Please, use Extended Events, not Profiler. From [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/sql-trace/observer-overhead-trace-extended-events): _"SQL Server Profiler is a tool to be avoided on busy production servers, as shown by the tenfold increase in duration and significant reduction in throughput for the replay."_

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to use `Extended Events` instead of `Profiler` as the `Extended Events` has less overhead and more events to capture compare to `Profiler`.

In your case, create a new session in Extended Events by selecting `rpc_completed` event. [For detailed steps..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: While I appreciate this is the better advice (and I shall be following it), it does not answer the specific question of how to do it in SQL Profiler. Thanks though.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I believe `rpc_completed` is the answer as it also available in profiler (if you still wish to use profiler)

Answer (score 4):

In your Trace Properties, I would recommend using the `Tuning` template.

Under the Event Selections tab in the Trace Properties, choose the `RPC:Completed` event under Stored Procedures.

Within the event filters tab, select `Show All Columns`.

Using the Column Filters:

> 1. DatabaseID **Equals** the DB_ID() of the database where the stored procedure exists.
> 2. ObjectName **Like** the exact name of your stored procedure without the schema.
> 3. ObjectType **Equals** 8272

This should capture what you are looking for.

More info regarding the `ObjectType` filter can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/objecttype-trace-event-column).

More information regarding the `RPC:Completed` event class can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/rpc-completed-event-class).

Depending on what version of SQL Server you are using, I would also consider taking a look at [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events). SQL Profiler will be removed in future versions of SQL Server.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to check `Show All Columns` in the `Trace Properties > Events Selection` in order to see the `ObjectName` filter. I changed `SP:StmtCompleted` to `RPC:Completed` to get my desired `TextData` capture of `exec sprocName @someparam...etc`. If you update your answer with these fixes then I will mark it as the correct answer.