# Unable to trace "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric" error in profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, profiler

I have a .net application. Its trying to create tables, views and insert/update data into many tables. while application running i got an error.

I tried to trace the query in SQL Profiler, but i didn't find any error. Is there any way to track the Error statement or Is there any other events i need to add in profiler.

I tried already following events (exception):

- RPC: Completed
- RPC: started
- SP: started
- SP: Completed
- SP: Stmtstarted
- SP: StmtCompleted
- SQL: Batchstarted
- SQL: BatchCompleted

Comment: Consider Xevents as replacement of profiler. To learn more ([Link1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/245285/185080), [Link2](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/sql-trace/observer-overhead-trace-extended-events), [Link3](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2144/an-overview-of-extended-events-in-sql-server-2008/))

Answer (score 5):

Using the follow link you can set everything up to track the exception [This link](https://nimblegecko.com/how-to-trace-sql-server-database-errors-and-exceptions-with-sql-profiler/)

In short: Set up a blank trace, add the following events :

- Exception under Errors and Warnings
- RPC: Completed under Stored Procedures
- RPC: Starting under Stored Procedures
- SQL: BatchCompleted under TSQL
- SQL: BatchStarting under TSQL

From there on, you can see the error popping up in the trace, the query above the error will be your query that's giving the error.

If that's not giving you the exception, i'd debug the .NET code to get the SQL code that's being executed, if you have access to the source code.

Comment: I used all options without warning. I cant able to track which sql/.net code cause problem.

Comment: Are you sure the error is in SQL, and not in your .NET layer? Or on a different instance than you're tracking

Comment: I used .net application. It contains both .net and sql scripts. While running an application I got an error.

Comment: Check you're tracing the correct server, make sure you're not connecting to test, while app is using prod or something. I tested above trace on a server here, and it returns the exception + code for both SPs and regular SQL code.

Comment: Also make sure you're not filtering out the database, perhaps the app connects to a different database than you think it's connecting to

Comment: I used filter. Because the application use only 2 databases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100515/discussion-between-b-muthamizhselvi-and-yannick-liekens).

Comment: You can filter the trace on ApplicationName, which you can set in your Connection String.